jenkins buils is not succesfully created
enter image description hereMY console output showing this error when ever I made a build
**Started by user jjjj
Running as SYSTEM
Building in workspace C:\Users\pc\PycharmProjects\Jenkins_Begin
[Jenkins_Begin] $ cmd /c call C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Temp\jenkins5101428332491164881.bat
C:\Users\pc\PycharmProjects\Jenkins_Begin>call C:\Users\pc\PycharmProjects\Jenkins_Begin.venv\Scripts\activate.bat
(.venv) C:\Users\pc\PycharmProjects\Jenkins_Begin>pytest--alluredir="C:\Users\pc\PycharmProjects\Jenkins_Begin.Reports"
'pytest--alluredir' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
(.venv) C:\Users\pc\PycharmProjects\Jenkins_Begin>exit 9009
Build step 'Execute Windows batch command' marked build as failure
[Jenkins_Begin] $ C:\allure-2.9.0\bin\allure.bat generate -c -o C:\Users\pc\PycharmProjects\Jenkins_Begin\allure-report
allure-results does not exists
Report successfully generated to C:\Users\pc\PycharmProjects\Jenkins_Begin\allure-report
Allure report was successfully generated.
Creating artifact for the build.
Artifact was added to the build.
Finished: FAILURE**
Image
can anyone help how to fix it

You are missing a space between your command and argument. It should be:
pytest --alluredir=....

Also, make sure pytest is properly installed and consider using:
python -m pytest --alluredir=...

If the above command doesn't work. Read more at the official doc.
